# Conditional formatting of a new variable

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

> ```
> Test1    Test2     Test3      Test4    
>   0        0         0          0        
>   0        0         0          0
>   1        0         1          0
>   0        0         0          0
>   0        1         0          1
> ```

Is there a way to create a new variable that will contain index "2" when "0" is in all variables Test* ? If there is "1" in at least one of the variables Test* the index in New_Var should be 0.
Thank you in advance.

Desired output:

> ```
> Test1    Test2     Test3      Test4    New_Var 
>   0        0         0          0         2     
>   0        0         0          0         2
>   1        0         1          0         0
>   0        0         0          0         2
>   0        1         0          1         0
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for this conditionally by summing all the variables in `test1-test4`. Since they're named this way, you can use the `sum(of var1-varn)` shortcut. If you use `sum(of test1-test4)`, SAS automatically translates this to `sum(test1, test2, test3, test4)`. This also works for arrays as well. For example, `sum(of arr[*])` will sum all the variables in the array `arr`.

```
data want;
    set have;

    if(sum(of test1-test4) = 0) then New_Var = 2;
        else New_Var = 0;
run;
```

```
Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4   New_Var
0       0       0       0       2
0       0       0       0       2
1       0       1       0       0
0       0       0       0       2
0       1       0       1       0
```